# Enable Web Inspector in Safari v 8.0 in Yosemite OS

Tags: macos, mac, bash

I'm trying to show/hide the web inspector tool in mac os "Yosemite" using bash script, I used the following command in terminal but it didn't work even after I restarted Safari, so am I doing something wrong?

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari WebKitDeveloperExtras –Boolean
```

Comment: Do you actually just write "boolean" or put a 1/0 there? (defaults write com.apple.Safari WebKitDeveloperExtras 0 or defaults write com.apple.Safari WebKitDeveloperExtras 1)

Comment: I tried commands you added but unfortunately didn't work too

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to hit Cmd/opt/i ?

Comment: No because I need to write this command in a mac application.

Comment: how about under NSGlobalDomain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defaults write NSGlobalDomain WebKitDeveloperExtras -bool true`

adds Inspect Element to the right-click menu

However, opening the Develop menu will do it too

`defaults write com.apple.Safari IncludeDevelopMenu -bool true`

One additional note about toggling the Develop menu this way is that it isn't interactive with the Safari prefs pane, & can result in reversed behaviour if later toggled from there by the user.